# Flutter Column: mainAxisAlignment.start not working

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I have the following situation:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Title"),
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I would expect to have the elements (and in particular the `Text`) aligned to the right, but this is not the case: 
[image: Resulting UI] 
 
Could someone please give me a hint about how to align the elements to the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start instead of mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start

A Column’s main axis is vertical.
A Column’s cross axis is horizontal.

> CrossAxisAlignment.start
>
> Place the children with their start edge aligned with the start side of the cross axis.

> MainAxisAlignment.start
>
> Place the children as close to the start of the main axis as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add crossAxisAlignemnt property to align the children of the column in horizontal position.
CrossAxisAlignment.start -> aligns left
CrossAxisAlignment.center -> aligns center
CrossAxisAlignment.end -> aligns right

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Title"),
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Column the Main Axis is Basically the y-Axis,
In the Column the Main Axis is Basically the x-Axis,
in your case you have to set the crossaxis not the mainaxis to align it to start
Try This Code

Column(
children: [
Container(
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Text("Cross Axis"),
],
),
),